# How to close a modal using javascript from code behind?

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

So far I have tried this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
 "closePage", 
 "window.returnValue='http://sp-pubdev:88/Resources/Images/testFile.png';
 alert(window.returnValue);
 SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);", true
);
```

and this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
 "closePage", 
 "window.returnValue='http://sp-pubdev:88/Resources/Images/testFile.png';
 alert(window.returnValue);
 window.close();", true
);
```

With both of these I will see my alter, but the window never closes.  Is there something else I need to be doing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In code behind u close model popup like this

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
                      Response.Flush();
                      Response.End();
```

I hope u use application page otherwise u not get Response object

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

1. [How to close show model dialog box in codebehind](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/f27a2eff-5588-42b2-b3f6-26303497166e/).

**EDIT**

I found this blog and goes into detail on closing a modal dialog!

[SharePoint 2010: Closing a ModalDialog Manually from Code (C# and JavaScript)](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2012/01/sharepoint-2010-closing-a-modaldialog-manually-from-code-c-and-javascript/).

Comment: Yeah they basically suggest the first method I was using.  I tried adding the second parameter to see if that would make it work, but no dice.

Comment: have you tried this:                                 void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
this.Context.Response.End();
}                                              http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f4edcb73-6864-4f1d-bc11-273e01c54367/

Comment: also this should work:   SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 'Submitted');